# How to use different variables for color and shape in a ggpubr ggline plot?

Tags: r, ggpubr

I am trying to create a line plot, using two different variables to specify colors and shapes respectively. But I get no plot and an error message in return, which I do not understand.

Preparing data frame

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:4, type = c("a", "b"), category = c("this", "that"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$val <- rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 5)
df$grp <- with(df, paste0(type, " ", category))
>   head(df)
  x type category      val    grp
1 1    a     this 4.266632 a this
2 2    a     this 6.512123 a this
```

Attempt to plot with shape and color specified:

```
ggpubr::ggline(data = df, x = "x", y = "val", group = "grp", shape = "type", color = "category")
```

Output:

```
Error in `purrr::pmap()`:
i In index: 1.
i With name: val.
Caused by error in `purrr::map()`:
i In index: 2.
i With name: group.
Caused by error in `if (is_parsable_aes(x)) ...`:
! the condition has length > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me. The issue is that you map different variables on `color` and `group`. If you just want different colors for the points you can do so by using `point.color=`. But if you want different colored lines then I'm afraid you have to create your plot from scratch using `ggplot2`:

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:4, type = c("a", "b"), category = c("this", "that"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$val <- rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 5)
df$grp <- with(df, paste0(type, " ", category))


set.seed(1)

library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

ggline(
  data = df, x = "x", y = "val",
  group = "grp", 
  shape = "type", 
  point.color = "category"
)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, val)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = grp, color = category)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = type, color = category)) +
  ggpubr::theme_pubr()
```

[image]